# Is linq query a memory leak if I don't use dispose method?

Tags: c#-4.0, memory-leaks, linq-to-entities

During a code review I was told to make sure that I do the dispose method for all query objects(LinqToEntities) I use.

Is this such a big memory leak? How can I fix this more elegantly, right now I don't do any dispose after I'm finished?

My code is the following:

```
var query = from x in listOfEntities where some_condition select x;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this query will not cause memory leak. Its the not the query which may cause the problem. Its probably the data context. Since the data context implements IDisposable you can do:

```
using (var ctx = new yourDataContext())
{
   var query = from x in ctx.listOfEntities where some_condition select x;
}
```

with `using` clause it will ensure that the connection to the database is closed after the code exits the using statement. It is similar to try/finally block.

```
var ctx = new yourDataContext();
try
{
    var query = from x in ctx.listOfEntities where some_condition select x;
}
finally
{
   if(ctx != null)
        ctx.Dispose();
}
```

EDIT:(Based on comments from @Fredrik Mörk). The above code is just to show you the usage of `using` statement with respect to `DataContext`.  To use the `query` object outside the using block, you may define it outside the `using` block and call `ToList` or similar method so that you get the execution of the query. Later you can use it. Otherwise due to deferred execution the current code block will fail.

Comment: I have not worked too much with entity framework so I may be completely wrong here, but will this not dispose the context before the query is executed (causing it to fail), due to LINQ's deferred execution?

Comment: @FredrikMörk I believe it will, as the query will be deferred until iteration, but I think it is simply a case of a sparse example to convey the disposal of items using a `using` or `try`, it doesn't attempt to explain subsequent further usage of the query.

Comment: @FredrikMörk, You have to define the query outside to use it and call some method like `ToList` to execute the query once. Later you can use it. My point of view was to show the usage of IDisposable.

Comment: @Habib: I am aware of the need to call `ToList` (or `ToArray`), that's why I commented. I think you should point it out in your answer, since the code will fail as it is presented now.

Comment: @FredrikMörk, thanks for the suggestion, I have edited my answer to reflect that. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Not specific to this situation, but whether a lack of calling `Dispose` will cause a leak or not is dependent on the inner workings of the disposable object. There are examples in the Framework of disposable objects that do little or nothing on dispose. Some implementations also only handle managed objects, which will be handled by the GC eventually anyway (so in this instance, you only lose *deterministic* disposal of objects, not necessarily causing any memory leaks).

The important part of the `IDisposable` contract is the convention that it brings to the table. You adhere to the contract regardless of the inner workings as the inner workings are open to change, the contract is not open to change. Although I'm not for blindly applying rules, I tend to always *try* to dispose items that I am using.